# Apache2 Error : Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

Im getting this in my apache2 error logs

```
  $[ pid=1388 thr=140670179071840 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:789 time=2012-03-30 18:44:52.209 ]: Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser, or the visitor's connection has stalled and couldn't receive the data that Apache is sending to it. As a res$
```

My site freezes after a short period and this is the error being shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 I've seen this too, though I've never had any performance problems as a result (Also: I think your error message got truncated).

Comment: @GarytheWorm is it that you experience this only on a specific browser like FF

Answer (score 0):

By a short time, what do you mean?  Seconds, minutes?  Under 30 seconds?  And is it consistent? Do you see the exact same delay each time?  Are you using unicorn? I know I am asking a lot of questions but at each layer there is a timeout that could be causing this issue.

I suggest upping the timeout on each layer.